# Include java applet class to my web page

Tags: java, applet, japplet

How can I include my java applet class into my web page using JSP on a netbeans web application project.
I don't want it as a jar. When I use a jar it works correctly.
I have a package named "com.example" which is the applet named Scan.java
Also have a web page named main.jsp which I added the code below.

I am using this code to include the class but

```
<APPLET CODE="Scan.class" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=250>
```

On the browser the applet doens't open and it says "ClassNotFoundException"

How to fix that?

Comment: don't do it - applets are so last century

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 3) Effectively, a class file that is not in a Jar cannot be used in a web page (using a modern JVM). We can only sign jar files.

Answer (score 1):

The class "Scan" should be on the same directory than your HTML/JSP page, or you could specify the relative path (from the JSP) to reach your Scan.class with the attribute CODEBASE.

```
<APPLET CODE="Scan.class" CODEBASE="../classes/com/example" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=250>
```